# Stop the execution of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On submit I do this:

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('input[name=published]').is(':checked')) p.validateImgs();

    //stop if p.validateImgs returns false
```

Validate Imgs Function:

```
p.validateImgs = function() {

    //Check Thumb
    var thumb = $('#thumb li .img-drop-zone');
    if(!thumb.has('img').length)thumb.addClass('error');

    //Check Galery
    var gallery = $('#gallery li .img-drop-zone').first();
    if(!gallery.has('img').length)gallery.addClass('error');

    //return true/false



};
```

How can I make it if false is returned from validateImgs, the submit script stops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form from submitting, how about

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e){

    if($('input[name=published]').is(':checked') && !p.validateImgs())
        e.preventDefault();

});
```

If you want to exit the function, use `return` as Jonathan mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a `function` early with a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Since it's conditional, place it under the `if` with `p.validateImgs()` as part of the condition:

```
if($('input[name=published]').is(':checked') && !p.validateImgs())
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

In validateImgs return true or false and capture the response in your submit function. Example.

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('input[name=published]').is(':checked')) 
    {
        response = p.validateImgs();

        // if any error
        if(!response)
        return false; // stop function

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Johan's code, but just add a little modification:

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e){
    if($('input[name=published]').is(':checked') && !p.validateImgs()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please notice the "return false" y added, just to be careful